# How to do resolve the 'jQuery not defined' error in Google Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, variables

Ok, sometimes the jQuery is defined and sometimes it is not. Here is the following jQuery code I am using on [this page](http://devs.dream-portal.net/dp11/index.php).

If it is defined, the columns are all the same width, else the two-side columns are 200 pixels and the middle is 100% width. I am trying to get jQuery defined at all times here, but can't figure out what the problem is exactly…

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!window.jQuery) {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.async = false;
   script.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
   var oScripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
   var s = oScripts[0];

   s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}

var totaltds = 0;
function resizeColumns() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('tr[class^="tablerow"]').each(function() {
            var tds = $(this).children('td[class^="tablecol"]').length;
            if (tds > totaltds)
                totaltds = tds;
        });
        var contentPadding = $("#content_section").css('padding-left');
        contentPadding = parseInt(contentPadding.substring(0, contentPadding.length - 2));
        var subPadding = contentPadding / totaltds;
        $(window).bind("resize", function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < totaltds; i++) {
                var colWidth = ($("#main_content_section").width() / totaltds) - subPadding;
                $(".tablecol_" + i).css({'width': colWidth + 'px', 'max-width': colWidth + 'px', 'min-width': colWidth + 'px'});
            }

        }).trigger("resize");

        $("#hideMe").parent().parent().parent().hide();
    });
}

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", resizeColumns, false);
else
    addLoadEvent(resizeColumns);

</script>

<div id="hideMe"></div>
```

All of this code is inserted into the body of the HTML, as it is inserted into a `Module` on that page, and needs to be that way. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to define jQuery so that it is always defined?

Chrome errors are almost all of the time on the line `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` saying that `jQuery` is not defined.

Comment: "All of this code is inserted into the body of the HTML, as it is inserted into a Module on that page, and needs to be that way." That seems to be your issue.

Comment: Is this code included in the page before the document is ready(meaning no ajax, but instead inline?)

Comment: Yeah, it's inline.  I've done this before and it works perfectly fine.  The jQuery gets inserted into the head, before the first script tag is defined.

Comment: Then it may be more appropriate to use document.write to force the script to be loaded and parsed before that script continues to execute. However if it ever gets included with ajax, it would break your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: If jQuery is undefined, add it to the `<head>`, and when completed, call `resizeColumns`. On `resizeColumns`, I added `noConflict` as well.

With this, the `undefined` will stop, since we will always wait the script gets fully downloaded before trying to use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Localize jQuery variable
 var jQuery;

 /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
 if (window.jQuery === undefined) {
      var jQueryTag = document.createElement('script');
      jQueryTag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
      jQueryTag.setAttribute("src",
      "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js");

      if (jQueryTag.readyState) {
           jQueryTag.onreadystatechange = function() { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                     resizeColumns();
                }
           };
      } else {
           jQueryTag.onload = resizeColumns;
      }
      // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
      (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(jQueryTag));
 } else {
      // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
      jQuery = window.jQuery;
      resizeColumns();
 }

var totaltds = 0;
function resizeColumns() {
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('tr[class^="tablerow"]').each(function() {
            var tds = $(this).children('td[class^="tablecol"]').length;
            if (tds > totaltds)
                totaltds = tds;
        });
        var contentPadding = $("#content_section").css('padding-left');
        contentPadding = parseInt(contentPadding.substring(0, contentPadding.length - 2));
        var subPadding = contentPadding / totaltds;
        $(window).bind("resize", function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < totaltds; i++) {
                var colWidth = ($("#main_content_section").width() / totaltds) - subPadding;
                $(".tablecol_" + i).css({'width': colWidth + 'px', 'max-width': colWidth + 'px', 'min-width': colWidth + 'px'});
            }

        }).trigger("resize");

        $("#hideMe").parent().parent().parent().hide();
    });
}

/* // Don't need that listener IMO

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", resizeColumns, false);
else
    addLoadEvent(resizeColumns);*/

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just wrap everything?:

```
// asynchronous function depending on jQuery
(function($){
    // define your shizzle
    var project = this,
        resizeColumns = function(){/**/};
})(jQuery);
```

This will also secure the `$` variable inside `this` function.

The same can be achieved by adding asynchronous functions to the DOM tree.

```
window.project = (function($){
    var resizeColumns = function(){/**/};
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
window.project = (function(){
    var $ = window.jQuery || {},
        resizeColumns = function(){/**/};
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible.  I do know that this needs to work if there are separate calls to jQuery on the page before this code gets run.  That is, if jQuery is already previously loaded, and if jQuery variables are being defined as something other than `$`

Comment: The first example is a shortcut into jQuery's `$.Deferred` object which returns a promise that window.load has been called. As you would write `$(window).load(function(){/**/});` Looks pretty solid I think ... ^^